# media query breakpoint ignores html min-width

Tags: html, css, media-queries, container-queries

So when I resize the browser window to less than 480px, my site changes back to the original style (the css not defined inside the mixins). I figured I'd work around this by just limiting the html with `min-width`, but although the browser gets a horizontal scrollbar, the css still changes. Why is that and how do I work around it?

```
html {
  min-width: 500px;
}

/********************************
HEADER
********************************/
.header img, .header h1 {
  float: left;
}
.header h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
  }
}
```

html for reference:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>ZIC Knjižnica</title>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900&subset=latin-ext,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="img/ijs_logo.gif">
            <h1>ZNANSTVENO INFORMACIJSKI CENTER</h1>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your smallest breakpoint specifies `(min-width: 480px)`, what did you  think was going to happen when you went smaller than 480px?

Comment: I thought I wasn't going smaller than 480px, because I specified html min-width.

Comment: You said you added the min-width on the html element as a "workaround".

Comment: somebody already explained enough in an answer so I think I understand. Thanks for trying anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting minimum or maximum dimensions on the root element does not restrict the dimensions of the viewport for the purposes of the `width` and `height` media features.

As you have observed, the browser creates a horizontal scrollbar once you resize the viewport to be narrower than 480px. The root element remains 480px wide because of its own `min-width` declaration, but the *viewport* is too narrow to contain it and that is why the scrollbar appears. Which means that the *viewport* is narrower than 480px and thus no longer matches the `(min-width: 480px)` expression.

You can't restrict the viewport dimensions in a desktop browser. If you want the styles in `(min-width: 480px)` to apply even when the browser window is smaller than 480px, remove the `@media` conditional entirely:

```
.header h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
...
```